# copy file to android during tests

Tags: android, adb, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

during the tests of my app, I need to copy video files from the project to device. I came up with this command:

```
    task copyFiles(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') {
    commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'file', /data/local'     
}
```

but I don't know exactly where to put it and how to invoke it on tests...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put file to /data/local (without hacks).
You can put it to /sdcard (internal memory on newest devices or external sd-card on old devices)